# How do auto update text input asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm doing a small project where I count Starting hour, Ending hour, and break hour and it will return how many hours I did work. 
My goal is to disable the **workedHours** text input have it auto update as you change the value of StartTime, EndTime and BreakTime.

This is my script how I calculate times:

```
$(function() {
    $('#startTime').change(function() { CalculateTime(); });
    $('#endTime').change(function() { CalculateTime(); });
    $('#breakTime').change(function() { CalculateTime(); });
    CalculateTime();
});


function CalculateTime() {
    try {
        var startTime = $('#startTime').val();
        var endTime = $('#endTime').val();
        var breakTime = $('#breakTime').val();

        var startDate = new Date(2000, 1, 1, startTime.substring(0, 2), startTime.substring(3, 5), 0, 0);
        var endDate = new Date(2000, 1, 1, endTime.substring(0, 2), endTime.substring(3, 5), 0, 0);

        var time = endDate - startDate;
        time = time / 1000 / 60 / 60;
        time = time - breakTime.substring(0, 2);
        time = time - (breakTime.substring(3, 5) / 60);
        $('#workedHours').html(time + " timmar");
    } catch (err) {
        $('#workedHours').html("---");
    }
}
```

And this is the view

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Start tid:</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.TextBox("startTime", Model.Times.StartTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Slut tid:</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.TextBox("endTime", Model.Times.EndTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Rast Längd:</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.TextBox("breakTime", Model.Times.BreakTime, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Tid jobbad:</label>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        @Html.TextBox("workedHours", Model.Times.WorkedHours, new { @class = "form-control timepicker timepicker-24" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Any guidance would be very helpful.

Comment: How are you representing duration with breaktime? Wouldn't you need a start/end for that as well?

Comment: Right now I have break time so you put into how many mins / hours you did take a break. So if you had 1 hours break. You simply just put in 1 hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My goal is to disable the `workedHours` text input

you can easily accomplish this with adding a `disabled` attribute to your input, as you're using Razor helpers, and as the name says, it's just a helper, you can use the normal tag:

```
<input type="text" id="workedHours" name="workedHours"
       value="@Model.Times.WorkedHours" class"form-control timepicker timepicker-24"
       disabled />
```

and btw, you can write this

```
$('#startTime').change(function() { CalculateTime(); });
$('#endTime').change(function() { CalculateTime(); });
$('#breakTime').change(function() { CalculateTime(); });
```

as this

```
$('#breakTime,#startTime,#endTime').change(CalculateTime);
```

but what you probably need is to use the `blur` method, simply change to:

```
$('#breakTime,#startTime,#endTime').blur(CalculateTime);
```

*remember*: "if you're duplicating code somewhere... you're doing it wrong"

---

*updated*

you also have an issue on the script, you're using `.html()` but you're using `input` 's so you need to use `val()`

change to:

```
$('#workedHours').val(time + " timmar");
```

live example: https://jsbin.com/guzeta/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: I were not aware of that, and I know I can disable it easy with the razor view engine, But I also want to have it auto update. If I change my Starting Time, I want the workedHours to auto update so those hours are correct. So if I start 1 hour earlier, I want workedHours to auto update make it say 9 hours instead of 8.

Comment: If I change Html() to .val I get NaN + "Timmar". 

How ever, i'll look into that Jsbin now and try to figure out what you did.

Comment: Werid, when I do inport Jquary-git it works. But it dosen't auto update, and the time Picker stops working. How ever as it's working on that I'll accept it as an asnwear and keep looking into my issue. Cheers.

Comment: it is wrong that has 2 calls to jQuery, as I added bootstrap and didn't see the script part... works the same [with just one call](https://jsbin.com/guzeta/2/edit?html,js,output) if you need more help, join the chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28967/

Answer (score 0):

Try this JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gt1cr0sz/2/

Add the Attribute

```
disabled="disabled"
```

to the Textbox workedhours.

Comment: The idea of writing an answer is to provide a new answer or a correct one, not to duplicate what an existing answer already says ;)